# Windows won't boot with grub installed with 16.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After using Ubuntu for some time I wanted to upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 and made a fresh install only to find out that I am not able to boot into Windows 10 anymore and trying to boot into Ubuntu gives me first an error.
When booting into Windows 10:

`Error: Symbol >>grub_efi_find_last_device_path<< not found.`

When booting into Ubuntu 16.10:

`Error: No symbol table.`

I have already tried to install grub again into /dev/sda and also tried to do boot-repair, but neither helped me. I found that maybe it's a bug in the new Grub (I am running version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu11), but I don't know which is the latest version that works. And is it possible to use and download only non-beta versions? Or does that beta in the version mean something else?

**EDIT**

Boot info [script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24229099/)

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: @RodSmith  I have added the link.

Comment: Your grub should be ok. The 2.02 beta is current version. Did you somewhere delete & recreate the ESP - efi system partition, your sda2? Grub even shows the  entry to boot /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi, but that does not exist in your UEFI. You can re-add that with Windows repairs or if you have a backup of the ESP just recover that. Do you have Windows repair or install flash drive with Windows repair console? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options

Comment: I'll add to what oldfred says that the Boot Info Script sometimes misses files, so it could be that `bootmgfw.efi` exists, but the script didn't report it. You might want to look for the file manually. If it's actually present, it's possible that my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) would work where GRUB doesn't, but that's a bit of a long shot. You can test it without risking damage to the installation by using the USB flash drive or CD-R version.

Comment: So I just installed 16.04(.2) again and now the Grub is working without any issue. Now I got the version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.8 installed (grub-common) and I am normaly booting into windows and ubuntu. I don't know what the problem was, but I think I am will stay for now with the LTS version.